# Docker build image issue

Tags: ubuntu, dockerfile

Error while building an image,please help me out from this[Error while building an docker image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dq4mU.png)

Comment: It would be better to write your code, instead of posting an image ;)

Comment: It’s been almost a year, why no chosen answer?

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 16126D3A3E5C1192` before your update in your dockerfile.

Answer (score 0):

This is quite an old problem and may be seen in older versions of ubuntu according to [ubuntuforums.org](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2194994)

So, there are two solutions:

1. Here's a solution link with some commands:

   http://www.ubuntugeek.com/how-to-fix-the-ubuntu-gpg-error-badsig.html

   You can include these commands in Dockerfile in `RUN` step
2. Use newer version of ubuntu as base image like `ubuntu:17.10` or `ubuntu:17.04`